# EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml using EditorFor() instead of Editor()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a generic editor template that replicates `Html.EditorForModel()`, to later customize and build upon. [Brad Wilson's template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) gets pretty close, but I found that it chokes when the same key exist in both ViewData (or ViewBag) and the model. For example `ViewBag.Title` causes problems if the view model also has a `Title` property.

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375323/binding-conflict-between-a-property-named-title-in-my-model-and-view-title-in-my/4774159#4774159) that using strongly-type helpers (i.e. `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Title)` instead of `Html.Editor("Title")` seems to help. So I tried to modify Brad's template, but I ran into a brick wall, as nothing I tried so far has worked. I can't figure out how to use strongly-typed helpers in a context where I don't know the model type, like an editor template for example.

Is there any way to create an Object template like Brad's, but using strongly-typed helpers (i.e. LabelFor, EditorFor, ValidatorMessageFor) instead of weakly-typed ones (i.e. Label, Editor, ValidatorMessage)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem in a slightly roundabout way, by removing the ViewData right before the call to @Html.Editor and then putting it back after.

**Object.cshtml:**

```
        object oldViewData = null;
        var hasConflictingViewData = ViewData.TryGetValue(prop.PropertyName, out oldViewData);

        if (hasConflictingViewData)
        {
            ViewData.Remove(prop.PropertyName);
        }

        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)

        if (hasConflictingViewData)
        {
            ViewData.Add(prop.PropertyName, oldViewData);
        }
```

The only other option I could think of is using a ton of reflection to call EditorFor generically with a runtime type, and pass in an expression for the pertinent property.

Comment: Sadly, this is the best solution for the ViewBag.Title problem.  It's a hack, sure, but it's a band-aid rather than a triple-heart bypass...

Answer (score 1):

You can view all of the code for the new Object.shtml by going and downloading the MVC source code. I thought it was also in some common folder on your pc already but I can't remember where.

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Comment: Yeah, they're in "\mvc3\src\MvcFuturesFiles\DefaultTemplates\DisplayTemplates\Object.ascx" and "\mvc3\src\MvcFuturesFiles\DefaultTemplates\EditorTemplates\Object.ascx". But they don't seem to use any of the strongly typed helpers, only the regular ones like Label(), Editor(), ValidationMessage(), etc. so they suffer form the same problem when there is a key in ViewData with the same name.

Comment: Are you saying when you make an editor template that it doesn't use the template you created?

Comment: No. I have no problems making editor templates and having MVC pick them up. My problem is that I can't figure out how to use strongly typed helpers from inside these templates. Templates don't have a @model directive, so the model metadata should have to come from somewhere else, like using reflection on the passed object. It is this last part I'm having problems with.

Comment: Can you explicitly set the model to a specific type?

Comment: I sure could. But that would defeat the point of having a generic template (it wouldn't be generic anymore.)

Comment: Wish I could help then, I would only suggest you use an interface but I know you don't want to do that